# Set Background Color using HEX

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I set a style color or background color to a HEX color using jQuery (or, for that matter, pure JavaScript as well), it seems to automatically convert it to its RGB equivalent.

How would I be able to set a style to a HEX color and have that same HEX color persist in the HTML (rather than have it convert to its RGB equivalent).

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cuhd8bgL/9/

```
$(function ()
{
    $("div").css("color", "#3282c3");
});
```

[image]

Comment: How about you set the style directly as a string?
$(function ()
{
 $("div").attr("style", "color: #3282c3");
});

Comment: @TedChirvasiu - the problem with this approach is that it would overwrite any other existing style values - so that would mean that I would have to write something that parse existing values to see if there is already a style value and update just that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [.attr( attributeName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and [CSSStyleDeclaration.removeProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) instead to use a regex:

```js
$("div").attr('style', function() {
  this.style.removeProperty('color'); // remove color if exist....
  return this.style.cssText + 'color:#3282c3;'; // add your color
});
$("div").each(function() {
  console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-family: Helvetica;line-height: 100%;margin-top: 20px; text-align: left;vertical-align: bottom;color: blue">
    I want a hex color! (I have already a style prop...)
</div>
<div>
    I want a hex color!
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `rgb(r, g, b)` is just an alternate to `#RRGGBB`. There is no functional difference.

So the browser may not store which syntax you used to specify the color at all and return any of the representations.

---

However, if you really want to have hex values the only option is to bypass all the style objects and assign the attribute value directly. Example:

```
document.getElementById('whatever').attributes['style'].textContent='background-color:#3282c3'
```

Comment: This is just a less-good version of NullPointer's solution above (since it uses JavaScript instead of jQuery).  My comment to their solution applies here as well - using this I then would have to check to see whether there are any existing styles and parse them to make sure they aren't over-written.

Comment: it's definitely not "less-good" if it's vanilla js instead of jquery. but thanks for the hint of having to parse existing styles! :~)